# Searching through children of an domain object in Grails GORM

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

How can I write this code correctly in Groovy / Gorm?

I have a *PageComponent* domain class that has many *Content*'s. I want to see if a particular *PageComponent* contains a *Content* with a specfific *key*.

I thought I could say:

```
def pageComponent = PageComponent.get(1);

if (pageComponent.contents.findByKey("textnode") {
  // update
} else {
  // insert
}
```

At the moment, I'm using this instead. Not very elegant...

```
def pageComponent = PageComponent.get(1);

def content = Content.withCriteria {
    eq "pageComponent.id", pageComponent.id
    eq "key", "textnode"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use dynamic finders:

```
Content.findByPageComponentAndKey(pageComponent, "textnode")
```